# Как решить проблему с yarn eject?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, git, командная-строка, yarn

Создал React проект 
после чего в командандной строке для моего проекта написал: **yarn eject**
и у меня вместо того чтобы появились зависимости новые выскочила ошибка:

[image]
И в конце вот что пишет:
[image]

Я загуглил что може быть, пишет что скорее всего git отслеживает изменение файлов.
Но я не нашел решение проблемы...
Сразу скажу Git вообще не знаю, не умею комитить и т.д.
Что конкретно прописать в командную строку?

Comment: `git reset --hard HEAD`

Comment: Судя по ошибке, и проект, и репозиторий у вас лежит прямо в папке пользователя (c:\users\username). И из-за этого гит пытается коммитать все подряд. Переложите его оттуда.

Answer (score 0):

в папке с проектом есть папка .git. если гитом не пользуетесь, просто удалите её и попробуйте снова. ошибок быть не должно. правда, если у вас eject как-то до конца доработал, то больше он не запустится. если вы создавали новый проект, создайте его снова, зайдите в папку проекта, удалите папку .git, а потом запускайте eject